# UNITY HDRP Broken Lighting on Build

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

**Hello Everyone!**

We are developing an indie horror game, and I have a huge problem on build (WINDOWS).
When I'm launching the game in playmode, the shadows and lighting are completely fine. But it has awful problem on build, because light starts randomly flickering, the shadows aren't rendering properly. Maybe that's a render pipeline problem or smth? (HDRP). We don't know what causes this problem. I tried to fix it with changing grass shader settings (because this problem appeared only when you light the grass, but then strange flickering appeared on other objects) and many other ways, but that's not a point. Also I tried to do something with baked lighting. I'd like to say that this problem was resolved before somehow, but now I'm facing with it again. Has anybody faced this problem before? Maybe that's only build problem?

There is Playmode video:
[Playmode Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eaxeFR9pNE)

And there is build video:
[Build Video](https://youtu.be/dMxn9btqJfU)

We will be grateful for any help!

Comment: doesnt look like lightning has anything to do with it.(as in flash rumble rumble in storms..  You mean "lighting?"   You havent mentioned what your build is for, what settings you set, the editor is well known for different results.  things like setting the grass not to throw a shadow may help with some of that.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

We imported Terrain Tools kit which has contained a GPU Instancing for the Details. We already had a GPU Instancing toggled on Material so they conflicted, and grass wasn't casting shadows properly.